# Hot reload doesn't work with Webpack configurations

Tags: reactjs, laravel

In my project `npm run watch` doesn't work, not sure what is the issue.
So my aim is to have a hot reload.
I also don't have a webpack.config file, just wondering if I need to have it?

Here is my package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.5",
    "cross-env": "^7.0",
    "laravel-mix": "^5.0.9",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
},
```

UPDATE:

This is the error I am getting:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js "--watch"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-02-04T03_42_21_351Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ watch: `npm run development -- --watch`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ watch script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-02-04T03_42_21_374Z-debug.log
```

Comment: You don't need a `webpack.config.json` if you want to use the default config since there is one that ships with Mix. What errors are you getting when you run `npm run watch` or `npm run hot`? Please add them to your question.

Comment: I have added, let me know if you need logs as well

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your package.json to the following, run `npm install` and then try your command.

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
        "cross-env": "^7.0",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.25",
        "react": "^17.0.2",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^4.0.0"
    }
}
```